# Stack View when printf is called?

Tags: c, assembly, stack, calling-convention

I was just learning about format string vulnerabilities that makes me ask this question

Consider the following simple program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char *s="SomeString";
printf(argv[1]);
}
```

Now clearly, this code is vulnerable to a format String vulnerability. I.e. when the command line argument is %s, then the value SomeString is printed since printf pops the stack once.

What I dont understand is the structure of the stack when printf is called

In my head I imagine the stack to be as follows:

grows from left to right ----->

```
main()                                                                  ---> printf()-->
RET to libc_main | address of 's' | current registers| ret ptr to main | ptr to format string|
```

if this is the case, how does inputting %s to the program, cause the value of s to be popped ?

(OR) If I am totally wrong about the stack structure , please correct me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack contents depends a lot on the following:

- the CPU
- the compiler
- the calling conventions (i.e. how parameters are passed in the registers and on the stack)
- the code optimizations performed by the compiler

This is what I get by compiling your tiny program with x86 mingw using `gcc stk.c -S -o stk.s`:

```
        .file   "stk.c"
        .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
        .ascii "SomeString\0"
        .text
        .globl  _main
        .def    _main;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_main:
LFB6:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $32, %esp
        call    ___main
        movl    $LC0, 28(%esp)
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        addl    $4, %eax
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        leave
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
LFE6:
        .def    _printf;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
```

And this is what I get using `gcc stk.c -S -O2 -o stk.s`, that is, with optimizations enabled:

```
        .file   "stk.c"
        .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
        .section        .text.startup,"x"
        .p2align 2,,3
        .globl  _main
        .def    _main;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_main:
LFB7:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $16, %esp
        call    ___main
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        movl    4(%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    _printf
        leave
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
LFE7:
        .def    _printf;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
```

As you can see, in the latter case there's no pointer to "SomeString" on the stack. In fact, the string isn't even present in the compiled code.

In this simple code there are no registers saved on the stack because there aren't any variables allocated to registers that need to be preserved across the call to `printf()`.

So, the only things you get on the stack here are the string pointer (optionally), unused space due to stack alignment (`andl    $-16, %esp` + `subl    $32, %esp` align the stack and allocate space for local variables, none here), the `printf()`'s parameter, the return address for returning from `printf()` back to `main()`.

In the former case the pointer to "SomeString" and the `printf()`'s parameter (value of `argv[1]`) are quite far away from one another:

```
        movl    $LC0, 28(%esp) ; address of "SomeString" is at esp+28
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        addl    $4, %eax
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp) ; address of a copy of argv[1] is at esp
        call    _printf
```

To make the two addresses stored one right after the other on the stack, if that's what you want, you'd need to play with the code, compilation/optimization options or use a different compiler.

Or you could supply a format string in `argv[1]` such that `printf()` would reach it. You could, for example, include a number of fake parameters in the format string.

For example, if I compile this piece of code using `gcc stk.c -o stk.exe` and run it as `stk.exe %u%u%u%u%u%u%s`, I'll get the following output from it:

```
4200532268676042006264200532880015253SomeString
```

All of this is pretty hacky and it's not trivial to make it work right.

Comment: Thats a brilliant answer, Thanks ! And I compiled it with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2' in GCC. With that, a '%s' as argv[1] would give me just "SomeString". I was stepping with GDB, and saw the stack traces, and in my compilation, ptr to %s (argv[1]) and the ptr to the string are stored and then the RET ptr is stored before going into printf.

Answer (score 0):

On x86 the stack on a function call could look something like:

```
          :              :
          +--------------+
          :  alignment   :
          +--------------+
12(%ebp)  |     arg2     |
          +--------------+
 8(%ebp)  |     arg1     |
          +--------------+
 4(%ebp)  |     ret      | -----> return address
          +--------------+
  (%ebp)  |     ebp      | -----> previous ebp value
          +--------------+
-4(%ebp)  |    local1    | -----> local vars, sometimes they can overflow ;-)
          +--------------+        
          :  alignment   :
          +--------------+
          :              :
```

If you used `-fomit-frame-pointer` `ebp` would not be saved on the stack. At different optimization levels some variables may disappear (be optimized out), ...

Other ABIs store function arguments on registers, instead of saving them on the stack. Later, before calling another function, live registers may spill into the stack.